# how can I make these four loop compute paralleling?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have a problem with MathWorks Parallel Computing Toolbox in Matlab. See my code below

```
for k=1:length(Xab)
    n1=length(Z)*(k-1)+1:length(Z)*k;
    MX_j(1,n1)=JXab{k};
    MY_j(1,n1)=JYab{k};
    MZ_j(1,n1)=Z;
end
for k=length(Xab)+1:length(Xab)+length(Xbc)
    n2=length(Z)*(k-1)+1:length(Z)*k;
    MX_j(1,n2)=JXbc{k-length(Xab)};
    MY_j(1,n2)=JYbc{k-length(Yab)};
    MZ_j(1,n2)=Z;
end

for k=length(Xab)+length(Xbc)+1:length(Xab)+length(Xbc)+length(Xcd)
    n3=length(Z)*(k-1)+1:length(Z)*k;
    MX_j(1,n3)=JXcd{k-length(Xab)-length(Xbc)};
    MY_j(1,n3)=JYcd{k-length(Yab)-length(Ybc)};
    MZ_j(1,n3)=Z;
end

for k=length(Xab)+length(Xbc)+length(Xcd)+1:length(Xab)+length(Xbc)+length(Xcd)+length(Xda)

    n4=length(Z)*(k-1)+1:length(Z)*k;
    MX_j(1,n4)=JXda{k-length(Xab)-length(Xbc)-length(Xcd)};
    MY_j(1,n4)=JYda{k-length(Yab)-length(Ybc)-length(Ycd)};
    MZ_j(1,n4)=Z;
end
```

If I change the for-loop to parfor-loop, matlab warns me that `MX_j` is not an efficient variable. I have no idea how to solve this and how to make these for loops compute in parallel?

Comment: `parfor` is NOT a magic wand. Are you sure you have optimised the loops as far as possible?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like you can combine it to one loop. Create combined cell arrays.

```
JX = cat(2,JXab, JXbc, JXcd, JXda);
JY = cat(2,JYab, JYbc, JYcd, JYda);
```

Check for the right dimension here. If your `JXcc` arrays are column arrays, use `cat(1,...`.

After doing that, one single loop should do it:

```
n = length(Xab)+length(Xbc)+length(Xcd)+length(Xda);
for k=1:n
    k2 = length(Z)*(k-1)+1:length(Z)*k;
    MX_j(1,k2)=JX{k};
    MY_j(1,k2)=JY{k};
    MZ_j(1,k2)=Z;
end
```

Before parallizing anything, check if this still valid. I haven't tested it. If everything's nice, you can switch to `parfor`.

When using `parfor`, the arrays must be preallocated. The following code could work (untested due to lack of test-data):

```
n = length(Xab)+length(Xbc)+length(Xcd)+length(Xda);
MX_j = zeros(1,n*length(Z));
MY_j = MX_j;
MZ_j = MX_j;
parfor k=1:n
    k2 = length(Z)*(k-1)+1:length(Z)*k;
    MX_j(1,k2)=JX{k};
    MY_j(1,k2)=JY{k};
    MZ_j(1,k2)=Z;
end
```

***Note:*** As far as I can see, the `parfor` loop will be much slower here. You simply assign some values... no calculation at all. The setup of the worker pool will take 99.9% of the total execution time.

Comment: Firstly,please accept the thanks from my deep heart. And as regards the efficiency of parfor loop here, It's really? If you can give me the real example to prove that the parfor loop here is not efficient, that will be so great!